# Excel - FIND function (case-sensitive) ignores case?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, text-search

Does anybody happen to know why the FIND function isn't case-sensitive here:

I used conditional formatting on my table with `=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$1:$B$13,A1)))`.
And the word "Rektor" in column B leads to a coloring of "Prorektor" in column A, even though it shouldn't if FIND is case-sensitive, or did I understand something wrong there?

[image]

Also, if anybody has an idea why the first cell of my array seems to stay unaffected by the formula, I'd be happy to hear it!
I'm using Excel Version 2301.

Many thanks!

### Solved with the help of Solar Mike's comment:

The formula needs the `,1` in the `FIND()` function: `=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND($B$1:$B$13,A1,1)))`
It works perfectly like this, finding all the correct fields.

Also perhaps helpful: I think for newer Excel versions it's `;` instead of `,` in the formulas.

Comment: Why does it miss the first Konsulent? And find() is case sensitive.

Comment: Also misses the first Radgiver...

Comment: Viv, your formula does works for me, without any issues, i will suggest you to use a `TOCOL()` to exclude the blanks `=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(TOCOL($B$1:$B$13,1),A1)))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya so it finds the first Konsulant? and the first Radgiver? Unlike the example shown??

Comment: Sir, it finds and highlights all the occurrences of the said words. `1064`, `1066`, `1276` & `1277` respectively

Comment: Viv you can also use this with the exisiting screenshot sample data you have shown, `=XMATCH(TEXTAFTER(A1," "),TOCOL(B:B))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya But the Op queries the word "Rektor", not 1064 or any of the other numbers.

Comment: I wrote it in short, it will not highlight `Rector` instead it would highlight `Konsulent`  & `Rådgiver` present in respective cells. Possibly they have selected wrong range in the Conditional Formatting.

Comment: That's a no in regards to the `;` in newer versions of Excel. It is called a list separator. In this case, it is used to separate each parameter of the function. The default (US) is a comma but some countries use a semicolon. Since this is a US website, we all post using the comma to avoid confusion. For example, on a German website, the contents will be posted using the semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show the behaviour of find():

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the `;1` did the trick!