# MS Excel find a value using wildcards and Vlookup

Tags: excel, match, wildcard, vlookup

I'm trying to match these two serial numbers from two different sheets.

- `05/000/0423/114` <---- `M1485`
- `05/000/0423/0114`

I have tried.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&M1485&"*";Sheet2!$A$2:$H$411;1;FALSE)
```

but no use it return **N/A**

I can't do it manually because there is too many random serial numbers.

Comment: Wildcard will certainly not work here, because both the serial numbers are different.  Instead try using this formula: `=VLOOKUP(TEXTJOIN("/",,TEXT(TEXTSPLIT(M1485,"/"),{"00","000","0000","0000"})),Sheet2!$A$2:$H$411,1,FALSE)` also you might need to change the comma separators as per your regional settings

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thank you for your reply unfortunately i can't use TEXTJOIN and  TEXTSPLIT because i'm using MS EXCEL 2019 
even if i can use these functions, i have serial numbers without "/"

Comment: So only one example is not enough, you may need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78133614/edit) the post with few more examples so others may share their suggestions as well

Comment: Without some clear examples I am not going to try, however find() or search() could give suitable results. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75912837/4961700